# Can I replace two run capacitors with a dual run capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, wiring, diy, hvac

In this unit https://ameristarhvac.com/wp-content/uploads/pdf/M4AC3-Air-Conditioner-Installation-Manual.pdf

Can I replace the 35 uF capacitor and the 6 uF capacitor with a 35/5 uF dual capacitor? If so, how do I wire it up. Here is the wiring diagram:

[image]

It looks to me like black on RC1 as well as black and orange on RC2 goes to common on the dual and yellow on RC1 goes to herm on the dual and brown on RC2 goes to fan on the dual? (I don’t have the optional RC3)

Note: this was a refurbished unit and I do not believe the capacitors are the originals so where would I check what the appropriate sizes are - I don’t see it in the manual and I don’t see 6 uF easily available on amazon or commonly used on other ones, which is why I’m looking at 5 uF on a dual

Here are the current capacitors:

[image]

[image]

And potential replacement: TEMCo Dual Run Capacitor RC0102-35/5 uF 370 V 440 V VAC Volt 35+5 uF AC Electric Motor HVAC https://a.co/d/12kViAL

Answer (score 1):

The exact value for run capacitors is generally not very critical, so IMO you will be OK using a 5/35 uF dual capacitor to replace the separate 35 uF RC1 and 6 uF RC2. I recently repaired a very old air conditioner by using two separate capacitors to replace the original dual can. Using a lower value is pretty safe, and may just result in a little less torque or speed for the fan. A higher value runs the risk of higher current in the auxiliary winding, which could result in overheating, but anything within 20% or so should work and be safe.

One way to determine the proper size of a PSC run capacitor is to try several values by adding small capacitors in parallel, and monitor the running current. The proper value should have the lowest current.